# Mapping some object keys into objects

Tags: javascript, validation, mapping

I'm trying to transform this object:

```
url = {
  page: 1,
  limit: 20,
  price_from: 1,
  price_to: 500,
  stock_from: 1,
  stock_to: 200
}
```

To:

```
consumableURL = {
  page: 1,
  limit: 20,
  price: {
    price_from: 1,
    price_to: 500,
  },
  stock: {
    stock_from: 1,
    stock_to: 200
  }
}
```

How is this achievable, in a reusable manner to account for other possible introduced keys in the feature?

And I'm guessing also with validation to make sure the two pairs exist before mapping them into an object?

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: So far, I created a filtered array of the object entries, that gets all those entries with keys which include either `from` or `to`.

Now I need to group them into array of arrays, something like this:
[ ["price_from": 1, "price_to": 500], ["stock_from": 1, "stock_to": 200] ]

Comment: the plan is then to use `Object.fromEntries` or something, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can split and check the result count to make the decision about the nested props.

```js
const url = {
  page: 1,
  limit: 20,
  price_from: 1,
  price_to: 500,
  stock_from: 1,
  stock_to: 200
};

const res = Object.entries(url).reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
  const splitArr = k.split('_');
  if (splitArr.length > 1) {
    obj[splitArr[0]] = obj[splitArr[0]] || {};
    obj[splitArr[0]][k] = v
  } else
    obj[k] = v;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

---

If it's going to be nested then you can use recursion or a nested loop. Here I'm using a nested reduce which will iterate over the split array to generate the deeply nested values.

```js
const url = {
  page: 1,
  limit: 20,
  price_from: 1,
  price_to: 500,
  stock_from: 1,
  stock_to: 200,
  stock_abc_to: 200,
  
};

const res = Object.entries(url).reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
  const splitArr = k.split('_');
  splitArr.slice(0, -1).reduce((o, key) => o[key] = o[key] || {}, obj)[k] = v
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Brilliant!

I cannot wrap my head around
`obj[splitArr[0]] = obj[splitArr[0]] || {};`

How does this exaclty do the magic of adding the prop if it exists only?

Comment: `obj[splitArr[0]] || {}`  ====> if `obj[splitArr[0]]` is defined then it will use that value... since an object is a truthy value.... if it's `undefined` then it will use the `{}` since `undefined` is falsy.....

Comment: @Sami : this may help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 1):

I think a following can be a possible solution with `.reduce()`:

```js
const url = {
  page: 1,
  limit: 20,
  price_from: 1,
  price_to: 500,
  stock_from: 1,
  stock_to: 200
};

const keys = ['price', 'stock'];

const entries = Object.entries(url);
const consumableURL = entries.reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  const contains = keys.some(e => k.indexOf(e) !== -1);

  if (!contains) {
    return {...a, [k]: v};
  } else {
    const prop = k.split('_')[0];
    return { ...a, [prop]: { ...a[prop], [k]: v } };
  }
}, {});

console.log(consumableURL);
```

Or in a shorter way which does not help the readability but works:

```js
const url = { page: 1, limit: 20, price_from: 1, price_to: 500, stock_from: 1, stock_to: 200 };
const keys = ['price', 'stock'];
const entries = Object.entries(url);
const consumableURL = entries.reduce((a, [k, v]) => !keys.some(e => k.indexOf(e) !== -1) ? {...a, [k]: v} : { ...a, [k.split('_')[0]]: { ...a[k.split('_')[0]], [k]: v } }, {});
console.log(consumableURL);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: It helps a lot but the problem is I do not want to be limited to `price` or `stock`

I want to make sure if I introduce a new pair of `something_from` and `something_to` in the future, it's still going to work.

Comment: In that case I would change the `contains` variable as the following: `const contains =  k.split('_').length > 1;`. So you are determining if it has `_` character without using the `keys` array what I introduced. I hope that helps!